# Moto G4 only boots into fastboot

Tags: adb, fastboot

I got the Moto G4 from Amazon and tried to use ADB and fastboot to unlock it, before realizing Amazon has oem-locked their version. In any case, now every time I turn on the phone it goes straight to AP Fastboot Flash Mode. I can then boot into the phone as usual, but it's really annoying to have to go through fastboot mode. Now I think it's interfering with an Android update. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bootloader enter:

fastboot oem fb_mode_clear

Then reboot, it should start normally from now on.